# How to reload a page in nativescript on page back?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

How to call page back again when calling $ navigateTo (Component) in nativescript and going back to $ navigateBack.

please answer about my question.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent user from closing a page by back button? if then you can directly listen to back button event and cancel it - read more on https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle

Comment: @Manoj I'll check. Thank you.